# Are integrals well defined over function spaces?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure and $f$ an integrable function defined over a function space $\mathcal{F}$. Assuming $\mathcal{F}$ belongs to some appropriate $\sigma$-algebra, is the integral
$$\int_{\mathcal{F}} f d\mu$$
well defined?

I tried doing looking up some results on the web and I was led to functional integrals, path integrals, and Bochner integrals. However due to my lack of knowledge on vector-measures I am unsure if any of these are what I am looking for.

If such an object exists, what is it called and how does it work? Further, is there any connection to these "function measures" and ordinary measures? For example, in the simplest case, is there some "Lebesgue measure" equivalent in this functional sense?

Comment: Integration can be defined on any measure space. The question you're really asking I think is whether on an (infinite-dimensional) there are some "standard" measures. Well, there is [no Lebesgue-type measure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure). Are there other interesting measures? Possibly (hopefully others can elaborate). Note that things like Bochner integrals are to deal with when the **target space** is a Banach space, NOT the domain, so it's the opposite of what you're looking for.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, so if I wanted both the domain to be a function space and the result of the integral to be another function (hence both infinite-dimensional) I would need a Bochner integral?

Comment: @CBBAM The Bochner integral can integrate any integrable Borel measurable function taking values in a separable Banach space. It is useful for extending results of complex analysis to functions that take values in a Banach space.

Comment: @Mason It seems that might be the object I am after, as I would like to integrate over a function space (which could be a Hilbert space) and output another function in a function space (which again could be a Hilbert space). Is there any Lebesgue measure equivalent for Bochner integrals?

Comment: I'll be more precise. Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $V$ is a separable Banach space. If $f : \Omega \to V$ is measurable and $\int_{\Omega}|f|\,d\mu < \infty$, then the Bochner integral $\int_{\Omega}f\,d\mu$ is well defined. See http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/vecint.pdf.